# Minimise LCS (a question from code chef starter division 61)

Tags: c++

I am beginner in coding. Yesterday I went through the lowest common subsequence problem in the starter division, but output is not coming. This code is in c++ and constraints are:

- 1≤T≤1000
- 1≤N≤ 10^5
- The sum of NN over all test cases does not exceed 2*10^5
- A and B contain lowercase English letters

Code:

````
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int lcs(string A,string B, int r){
    int n,m;
     int dp[n+1][m+1];
       for(int i =0; i<r;i++){
        dp[i][0] = 0;
       }
        for(int i =0; i<r;i++){
        dp[0][i] = 0;
       }
       for(int i= 1; i< r; i++){
        for(int j= 1; j< r; j++){
        if(A[i] == B[j]){
                dp[i][j] = 1+dp[i-1][j-1];
                 
                }
                else{
                    dp[i][j]= max(dp[i-1][j] ,dp[i][j-1]);
                }}}
       cout<<dp[n][m]<<endl;
     } 

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int t ;
      cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int r;
        string B;
          string A;
       cin>>r; 
       cin>>A;
       cin>>B;
      cout<<lcs(A,B,r)<<endl;
      }
      return 0;
  }```





input
3
4
aaaa
aaab
1
c
z
5
abcde
cdefg
````

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?  What did you learn?  What's an example of sample input that causes your program to fail?

Comment: you never initialise n and m, and even if you did the way you using them is not valid c++

Comment: Tactical note: Judging and competition sites like Code Chef are generally intended for folks experienced with the language and looking for practice or just like to have fun solving random problems. They are not intended to teach, so trying to learn from such sites tends to turn into an exercise in frustration.

Comment: Note: Neil Butterworth has already hinted at this, `int dp[n+1][m+1];` Is not legal in Standard C++ and won't work with many compilers. The compilers that do have an extension that allows usually it follow the example of C99 and allocate the array in Automatic Storage (on the stack). You don't get much automatic storage, typically 1 to 10 megabytes, so an `n` and `m` as small as a few hundred may overflow the stack. In general, don't let the user specify the amount of stuff that goes on the stack, this includes recursion, unless you enforce really tight bounds.